# Streaming large SOAP response in Java from memory to database without any interim disk usage

Tags: java, memory, soap, streaming, mtom

I have a question on how to stream large MTOM attachment response at the client side from memory to an Oracle database without any temporary disk usage.

I already have a working implementation which does following things in sequence:

1) Parsing of entire MTOM response (used xercesImpl to avoid OutOfMemory error)

2) Saving the parsed data to CSV file on disk

3) Reading CSV row by row in a loop and do 3a and 3b in each iteration until all the records are consumed:-

3a) Additional processing on CSV row data in memory.

3b) Loading the processed row data from memory to an Oracle database.

The above implementation is working fine but it's not very efficient since we are getting the entire response in memory before saving it to disk and then again start reading records back from disk to memory before loading into a database.

I want to avoid the entire disk usage flow which means no CSV file or any interim temporary file.

I have tried the StreamingAttachmentFeature with both eager and lazy parsing along with  [StreamingDataHandler](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.7/javadocs/com/sun/xml/ws/developer/StreamingDataHandler.html) but it was creating a temporary file on disk and saved the entire response in it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Suggestions would be really appreciated. Anyone?

Comment: This is probably not an answer, but I implemented something similar here: https://github.com/king-for-a-day/StreamingService
It's also on bintray https://bintray.com/avidd/maven/StreamingService/view

This is a ResponseType for SOAP messages that streams protocol buffers. It does not use any intermediate files. You could use an individual Protocol buffer for each CSV row.